# Call a function as fast as possible for 5 seconds in php

Tags: php, sockets, networking, udp

I am using php to make a programm that collects data from different servers. I try to send a lot of udp packets to different servers like this:

```
$socketList = stream_socket_client('udp://'.$ip , $errno, $errstr, 1);
stream_set_blocking($socketList, 0);
fwrite($socketList, "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x66\x73\x74\x64\x05");
```

It’s planned that some of the servers that get the packet won’t answer. In that case i try to send another packet. I am using the non-blocking mode because i don’t want to have a 1 second timeout for every of the servers that won’t answer. So my idea is to first send all the packets and then wait in a while loop for 5 seconds for all the packets using this function:

```
$data = fread($socketList, 2048);
```

My problem is that i don’t know how to make a while loop in php that runs as fast as possible for 5 seconds.

I also don’t know if it has to run as fast as possible to don't miss a packet. Would something like this catch every packet too?

```
for($i = 0, $i = < 50, $i++) {
    $data = fread($socketList, 2048);
    sleep(0.1);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sockets have buffers, you probably won't miss any packets.

Comment: So i could just wait for some sec until i think all packets have to be there and then get all?

Comment: Yeah you could wait a timeout period then read all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets have buffers, you probably won't miss any packets. –  Bun Jul 4 '14 at 13:42

So i could just wait for some sec until i think all packets have to be there and then get all? –  Tim Jul 4

Yeah you could wait a timeout period then read all responses. –  Bun Jul 4 '14 at 14:15